# SQL records/subtype/custom variable type

Tags: database, sqlite, record, subtype, visual-paradigm

I'm currently doing an internship and I have to convert an Excel table to an SQL based database.
I have no idea how to even approach the problem I'm having.

First, my database contains a table of Elements (it's in German, the columns are abbreviation, atomic number and so on):

[image: A list of Elements]

I need to create another table in my database called Configuration of Products.

This table contains parts of servers:

ID: 1: Part: Chips

ID: 2: Part: Magnets

ID: 3: Part: CPU

For each part of the server, I need to add how much (in mg/kg) of each Element (like Gold, Silver) it contains, like this:

[image: Configuration]

I don't want the variable to be called (for example) Gold and to be of type double (for the weight). I want the variable to be of the whole record of the Element Gold, basically creating a record variable for each row of the Element table and make have these as the variables of each column of my Configuration table. The datatype I'm adding is a double.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to use a link entity between Server Part and Element to record the weight of element used in each server part.

[image]

BTW, if you model with Visual Paradigm you can go to Tools > DB > Generate Database generate DDL statements for your DB schema, or directly output the schema into your database.

[image]

More details about database engineering features in Visual Paradigm can be found at https://circle.visual-paradigm.com/docs/database-design-engineering/